# How many times do I get to use Winter Spirit in a Rapid Shot?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

I'm a Hunter multiclass Seeker, Paragon Multiclassing paragon path.

I have a Seeker encounter power called **Winter Spirit** from my paragon path that has a Special entry that reads:

> You can use this power as a ranged basic attack.

I also have **Rapid Shot** from Hunter which has an Effect entry that reads:

> You make a ranged basic attack with a weapon against each creature in or adjacent to a square within the attack's range. You take a -2 penalty to the attack rolls.

If I use Winter Spirit with Rapid Shot can I use it with each attack I make? Or just one and the rest are regular RBA's? Or could I use Winter Spirit with one attack and use other powers useable in lieu of a RBA for the rest?

Answer (score 4):

Although the entry does say you can use it as a RBA and normal RBA's are at-will, I believe the power you're using supersedes a normal RBA.

In other words, the ***Special*** feature states that you use ***this*** power as the RBA, so if that power is an encounter power, it remains as such. Otherwise Seekers essentially get a new at-will power whenever they pick up the encounter power that has the ***Special*** entry.

So to answer your question directly; you can use any power that has that *Special* entry as a RBA with *Rapid Shot*. However, if it's an encounter power it still has to follow the rules of an encounter power (can only be use once per encounter and only if you haven't already expended it's use, and it can't be used again until you take a short rest).